# replace spaces with null value using regexp_replace if i have multiple

Tags: scala

How to replace spaces with Null if i have spaces in multiple column.

```
Input Dataset which i have
+---+-----++----+
| Id|col_1|col_2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|104  |     |
|  1|     |     |
+---+-----+-----+
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val test = df.withColumn("col_1","col_2", regexp_replace(df("col_1","col_1"), "^\\s*", lit(Null)))
test.filter("col_1,col_2 is null").show()
```

Output Dataset:

```
+---+-----++----+
| Id|col_1|col_2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|104  | Null|
|  1|Null | Null|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use one withColumn for each column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = List(("0", "104", "    "), ("1", " ", "")).toDF("Id","col_1", "col_2")

val test = df
  .withColumn("col_1", when(regexp_replace (col("col_1"), "\\s+", "") === "", null).otherwise(col("col_1")))
  .withColumn("col_2", when(regexp_replace (col("col_2"), "\\s+", "") === "", null).otherwise(col("col_2")))
  .show
```

Result

```
+---+-----+-----+
| Id|col_1|col_2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|  104| null|
|  1| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: notebook:2: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
        signature: Column.getItem(key: Any): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: Column.getItem((): Unit)
  .withColumn("Name", if(col("Name").getItem().toString().replaceAll(" ", "").equals("")) lit(null) else col("Name") )

Comment: I am getting this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()

Comment: @PraveenSaini  now is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can do like this:

```
scala> val someDFWithName = Seq((1, "anurag", ""), (5, "", "")).toDF("id", "name", "age")
someDFWithName: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> someDFWithName.show
+---+------+---+
| id|  name|age|
+---+------+---+
|  1|anurag|   |
|  5|      |   |
+---+------+---+
scala> someDFWithName.na.replace(Seq("name","age"),Map(""-> null)).show
+---+------+----+
| id|  name| age|
+---+------+----+
|  1|anurag|null|
|  5|  null|null|
+---+------+----+
```

Or try out this also:

```
scala> someDFWithName.withColumn("Name", when(col("Name") === "", null).otherwise(col("Name"))).withColumn("Age", when(col("Age") === "", null).otherwise(col("Age"))).show
+---+------+----+
| id|  name| age|
+---+------+----+
|  1|anurag|null|
|  5|  null|null|
+---+------+----+
```

Or For more than one space try out this:

```
scala> val someDFWithName = Seq(("n", "a"), ( "", "n"), ("         ", ""), ("  ", "a"), ("   ",""), ("        ","   "), ("c"," ")).toDF("name", "place")
someDFWithName: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, place: string]

scala> someDFWithName.withColumn("Name", when(regexp_replace(col("name"),"\\s+","") === "", null).otherwise(col("Name"))).withColumn("Place", when(regexp_replace(col("place"),"\\s+","") === "", null).otherwise(col("place"))).show
+----+-----+
|Name|Place|
+----+-----+
|   n|    a|
|null|    n|
|null| null|
|null|    a|
|null| null|
|null| null|
|   c| null|
+----+-----+
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: I have tried it in databricks but it is not working. please see below code and respective output.                                                                                                   
odr.na.replace(Seq("name","age"),Map(""-> null)).show                                                                                                                   +----+-----+
|Name|Place|
+----+-----+
|   N|    a|
|   a|     |
|   a|     |
|   a|     |
|    |     |
|   b|     |
|   c|     |
|   c|     |
|     |     |
|   d|     |
+----+-----+

Comment: @PraveenSaini please try out this:
`odr.na.replace(Seq("Name","Place"),Map(""-> null)).show`
Please make changes into the query according to the requirement. Don't copy paste blindly.

Comment: Not working i tried as you instructed. is there anything which i  am missing ?

Comment: Can you please provide your all query like how are you creating DF? What are you trying to filter out the things?

Comment: @ Learner I have excel file which i am importing from DBFS and create dataframe. So in my file there are various column which is having space but i want to remove all the spaces which 'null'.

Comment: What is the name of the DF?

Comment: odr is name of my dataframe. I am trying with databricks spark scala.

Comment: Okay @PraveenSaini, Please try this:
odr.withColumn("Name", when(col("Name") === "", null).otherwise(col("Name"))).withColumn("Place", when(col("Place") === "", null).otherwise(col("Place"))).show

Comment: @ Learner I have tried this it is working for me .odr.withColumn("Name", when(col("Name") === " ", null).otherwise(col("Name"))).withColumn("Place", when(col("Place") === " ", null).otherwise(col("Place"))).show

Comment: I found one issue in this while testing with various spaces instant of single space it won't work. suppose i have 3 space in my column than it is not converting that place as null.